# img inside iframe and hover effect

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a problem with hover effect on elements that are inside `<iframe>`.

Code inside iframe, it's in `domainA.com`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
          img:hover {
            opacity: 0.5;
          }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <img src="/image1.jpg">
     <img src="/image2.jpg">
     <img src="/image3.jpg">
 </body>
</html>
```

And second website on `domainB.com`

```
<iframe src="domainA.com/iframe.html">
```

When i embed iframe in domainB hover effect doesn't work. Is there any way to solve it somehow? I don't have access to code of domainB.com (other developer will put iframe there)

Comment: You have to write this `CSS property` in original page. You cannot inject `CSS` to `iframe` directly.

Comment: Hmm, but what if i don't have access to original page? Iframe is not in the same domain origin

Comment: @Astaz3l Then its not possible if origin is not same.

Comment: ;/ could this be done via js for instance? kind of mouseover or something?

Comment: @Astaz3l it can be done via js if origin domain of `iframe` and `parent` page is same. If its really required extract text from `iframe` and `append` it to your `parent` page

Comment: @Deadlock problem is that i'm providing iframe and i don't have access to parent page code

Comment: @Astaz3l I know you don't have access. What I am saying is to scrape required text with `js` if its `DOM` structure is fixed.

Comment: @Deadlock not sure if i understand. Could you provide any snippet or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you want this effect work,you should link this css to inside your iframe.

a.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe src="b.html" ></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
img:hover{
   opacity: 0.5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="xx.jpg" />
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise use javascript to do this...like:

```
$(document.getElementById('Iframe_id').contentWindow.document.body).find("image").mouseover(function(){
   alert("do what you want here");
});
```

Be sure this code is inside `$(documet).ready();`

Comment: Iframe is not in the same domain origin and he cannot access orignal page

Comment: @Deadlock,he didn't mention it before,then he can use javascrpt

Comment: @RayCheng could you give me any tip how to achieve that? I don't have access to parent page code

Comment: @Astaz3l,i'll update my answer,please check..

Comment: @RayCheng cool, but the problem is that I can't add anything to parent window code. So if possible, it has to be done from the inside of iframe + it's not in the same domain so contentWindow will not work

Comment: @Astaz3l,it's better put you code to us,then i can see what you really want..

Comment: @RayCheng i've edited the question with source code. It should be more clear now